# asp.net MVC c#, model List<t> binding and saving data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that handles a ViewModel as below,

```
public class MyVM {
    public Exercise exer{ get; set; }
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public List<ExerciseInput> inputs { get; set; }
}
```

The view has multiple exercises based on the number of categories in the database. With a for loop i create the initial exercises for each category, the user can also add a question to each category too (as linked in has in it profile page, you can add experience to the profile), my issue is saving all this data. or updating existing data. I used Editor templates, but still can figure out how to handle multiple data for each category of the same type (ExceriseInput). 
Thanks in advance.

Controller code,

```
public ActionResult viewExcerciseDetails(int Id)
        {
            var vm = new MyVM();

            vm.exer= db.Exercise .SingleOrDefault(m => m.exerId == Id);
            vm.categories = db.Categories.OrderBy(m => m.orderNum).ToList();
            vm.inputs = db.ExerciseInput.Where(m => m.exerId == Id).ToList();

            return View(vm);
        }
```

A piece of code where the for loop in the view

```
@for (var i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => data[i])
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: sorry i use a for loop, just a type, updated code above.

Comment: Your model is `MyVM` which does not even contain a property named `data`! Read the answer I linked to.

Comment: You are correct, data variable is just a filtered version of my model. I am looking at your posted question, thanks.

Comment: Don't change the code when someone is suggesting a solution or pointing out issues...creates confusion..

Comment: So i can have one form for rhe whole page that saves the chabged data. And how can i update the model when lets say the user adds one new excercise to a category? How would the view handle 2 kind of forms?

Comment: If your wanting to dynamically add and remove collection items, refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
1. Change your `ViewModel` to the below code

```
public class MyVM {
    public Exercise exer{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ExerciseInput> inputs { get; set; }
}
```

2. Then in the controller add the data, which is like your code.
3. Then in the view, populate the `categories` and `inputs` by Editor Template.
4. The Editor Template files should be in the name of respected model name like `Category` and `ExerciseInput`.
   Hope this helps

Comment: There is no need to change the view model.